# C++ what should I use instead of #define

Tags: c++, expression, constants

I would like to give a value from the console with cin operator instead of using a #define N 6.
I've tried it but I get "expression must have constant value" error message.
How should I do it by the other way?

Thank you for answers!

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#define N 6
using namespace std;

typedef struct person {
    int roll;
    string name;
} Person;

int main() {
    int numberofperson;
    cout << "Number of people: "; cin >> numberofperson;
    srand(time(NULL));
    Person people[N];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberofperson; i++)    {
        cout << "Write the " << i + 1 << ". name of the person: ";
        cin  >> people[i].name;
        people[i].roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
        cout << "Roll with dice: " << people[i].roll<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The dimension of an array cannot be a runtime variable in C++. Use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defines are unrolled with the preprocessor. In fact, `#define N 6` means that all occurrences of `N` in your code will be replaced by `6`, thus replacing `cin >> N` with `cin >> 6`.

The solution is to make `N` a variable:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
// do whatever you want with N
```

However, note that in this case `Person people[N]` is a variable-sized array (that is, its size is not known during compilation time. It is non-standard C++ and you should avoid it. Consider using [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead – it is basically a variable-sized array from the standard library.

```
cin >> N;
vector<Person> people(N);
...
cin >> people[i].name;
```